# A quite tiny riley

Tags: riddle, affix-riddle

My prefix, thus used, is tiny
My suffix, perused, is tiny
My infix, confused, is tiny
My whole is revolting if briny

Answer (score 5):

I wonder - given recent jokes within The Sphinx's Lair (the main PSE chatroom) - whether the answer is:

> **PICKLE**

*My prefix, thus used, is tiny*

> **PI** is tiny in the sense that it is a single Greek character (or 'only' 3.141... when considered as the mathematical constant).

*My suffix, perused, is tiny*

> **ICKLE** is a synonym of 'tiny', often used in baby language or particular regional dialects (e.g. West Midlands, in the UK).

*My infix, confused, is tiny*

> *LICK* is an *anagram* (note the cryptic clue indicator 'confused') of **ICKL**, and can be used to mean 'a small application of something' (e.g. 'a lick of paint').

*My whole is revolting if briny*

> Recent chats in The Sphinx's Lair have often (who knows why...) descended into discussions about whether or not pickles (the food) are disgusting or not. It appears that the OP falls firmly into the disgusted camp, considering them 'revolting' in this riddle! (NB 'Briny' can be used as a synonym for 'pickled'...)

Comment: Hahaha! Nice one :o

Answer (score 4):

My whole is revolting if briny

> a salty **secretion** may sometimes be revolting

My prefix, thus used, is tiny

> **sec** - a second or very short period of time

My suffix, perused, is tiny

> **ion** - atomic sized and tiny to view

My infix, confused, is tiny

> **[trice](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trice)** - a brief moment of time, is the infix anagrammed

Answer (score 3):

> Thus used, my prefix is tiny

> sic, a *small* word for "thus used" [though not an abbreviation]

> Perused, my suffix is tiny

> bag: People fold up newspapers *small* to make paper bags.

> Confused, my infix is tiny

> KBA, an *abbreviation* for "knowledge-based authentication": KBA uses confusion as a barrier.

> My whole is revolting if briny

> sick bag: It's revolting if it's been used and is thus briny.

Comment: That's impressive, but not the answer I had in mind